# Fantasy/Isekai? about deliveryman

Tags: story-identification, manga

This is fantasy (I believe it is not isekai though not 100% sure) Japanese novel/manga about guy/boy that delivers various things.
He changed his class from Dragon Knight/Tamer (?) that was one of the most powerful classes to Courier/Deliveryman. He utilizes bag (that is passive skill) that is very OP - one scene I remember is him using this bag as catching attack/fire beam and redirecting it to enemy.
I do not remember much else just that when he changed class real goddess/angel descended and asked if he was sure about changing his class.

Comment: You should self-answer rather than editing the question

Comment: *From The Strongest Job of Dragon Knight, To The Beginner Job Carrier, Somehow, The Heroes are Depending on Me* is actually pretty good. No great

Answer (score 2):

Placeholder answer until the querent posts the answer they edited into their question, *[From The Strongest Job of Dragon Knight, To The Beginner Job Carrier, Somehow, The Heroes are Depending on Me](https://myanimelist.net/manga/118168/Saikyoushoku_Ryuukishi_kara_Shokyuushoku_Hakobiya_ni_Natta_noni_Nazeka_Yuusha-tachi_kara_Tayoraretemasu_comic)*, aka *Saikyoushoku "Ryuukishi" kara Shokyuushoku "Hakobiya" ni Natta noni Nazeka Yuusha-tachi kara Tayoraretemasu* or *最強職《竜騎士》から初級職《運び屋》になったのに、なぜか勇者達から頼られてます*

[image: Front cover of From The Strongest Job of Dragon Knight, To The Beginner Job Carrier, Somehow, The Heroes are Depending on Me]

> Axel Granz, the strongest dragon knight of them all has switched his job to become a beginner carrier. Relieved that he can finally take off his legendary dragon knight’s helmet and escape the responsibilities of an elite S-class worker, Axel eagerly starts his new, low-class job!

Comment: Feel free to copy and or all of this answer for your own, and I'll delete mine.